# Alternative to Fiddler?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, proxy

Hi I use [Fidder](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to test bug fixes directly on non development environments. It allows you to intercept the bogus javascript file and replace it by any other content you specify without needing to deploy any files.

The problem is that I just use this feature from Fiddler, and the interface is not very user friendly (specially if you need to replace/intercept more than one file, it gets quickly tedious).

> Is there an alternative software with
>   the same feature and more user
>   friendly/productive ? Or even better,
>   one that integrates easily with your
>   IDE (personaly I use eclipe) ?

Comment: I'd love to learn about what you think is tedious, since the AutoResponder makes this *extremely* easy.

Comment: I love the AutoResponder feature (think I even suggested adding it once before it existed, though I was probably not the first person to do so ;-)) - and I just figured out it has drag-and-drop functionality. Select one or more sessions, drag them to the AutoResponder pane - voila. Right-click one or more entries and click "Create file", then you can use your favourite editor. A little bit naughty to put the generated files on my Desktop but otherwise brilliant. EricLaw is a UI genius IMO :)

Answer (score 6):

Give [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) a go.  I find the interface a bit better than Fiddler.  It's not free, but has a demo which runs for thirty minutes, at which point you can restart it.

Not sure if it has the all the features you want though, you might have to give it a go.

Comment: This comment whereby fiddler is Windows only is now obsolete, the fiddler website now states "Debug web traffic from any Windows-based PC, Mac or Linux system and mobile devices alike."

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at Burp Suite.  It's free and once you master it you can do some very powerful things with very little effort.

http://portswigger.net/burp/

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler is plugable and it's not hard to edit the script that comes with fiddler to achive your goal or better still write you own filter with a few lines of code and then drop the DLL in the fiddler2 folder.

The code you need is something like

```
if (oSession.url.indesOf("XYZ")>-1)
  oSession.LoadFromFile("c:\\MyScript.js");
```

I wrote a muiltithread proxy server from scratch, zillion lines of code, months of work and a big mistake because Fiddler gives you all the tools you need out of the box and it's so easy to extend and i will be releasing some code that gets Fiddler to kick back against the spyware servers in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using firefox with tamper data.